# Calculate date difference in months

Tags: c#, .net

I have a field returning a year and month value.  For example, 20119 (2011 is year and 9 is for September).  How could I compare that to the current year and month to get the difference in months?  For example, in the same format the current year and month would be 20135, so the value I would be looking for would be 20.  20135 minus 20 months would be 20119.  Not sure how to construct the formula to dynamically calculate the difference in months using date functions, perhaps.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you haven't tried anything, look into the [AddMonths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx) method of the DateTime object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
DateTime x1 = DateTime.ParseExact("20119", "yyyyM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime x2 = DateTime.ParseExact("20135", "yyyyM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

int months =  Math.Abs((x2.Month - x1.Month) + 12 * (x2.Year - x1.Year));
```

Comment: Should the format be "yyyyM" instead of "yyyym" (months instead of minutes)? When I tried it that gave me x1 = 01/01/2011 12:09:00 AM

Comment: @Greg, yes it should be M

Comment: Thanks rs.  Is there any easy way to convert the current date into the "20135" format?  Instead of having to take the year part of the current date and concatenate that to the month part of the current date.

Comment: @obautista, try - `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyM")`

Answer (score 1):

Why not multiply the year by number of months in a year for each date field and then return the difference?

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding you right. Are you saying: date1 = 20139 and date2 = 20138 (1 month difference). 2013*9-2013*8=2013.

Comment: (2013*12+9) - (2013*12+8)

Comment: Ah - that makes much more sense. Very clever.

Answer (score 1):

First I am assuming that by your question:

- Single date months will have one digit
- The value of the Year+Month is a string (if it is an int, throw a ToString() on the in value in the code below)

Your value thus will be 5-6 digits in length.  You can perform the code below in less lines, but forgive my verbose answer - I will add extra code to make this more clear:

We can get the current date only as month year by getting using Date.Now

```
// Just want the month/year
DateTime currentDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
```

Now we can get your date for to test against the current year/month using a substring method (remember my assumption that we are dealing with a string value, and to convert ToString() if not).

```
    // breaking out test date to year/month portions and saving as a new date time
    string testDateValue = "20119";
    int testDateYear = Convert.ToInt32(testDateValue.Substring(0, 4));
    int testDateMonth = Convert.ToInt32(testDateValue.Substring(4));
    DateTime testDate = new DateTime(testDateYear, testDateMonth, 1);
```

Now lets get the difference:

```
// get month dif - remove abs() if want negative if test date in future
int numberOfMonths = Math.Abs(((currentDate.Year - testDate.Year) * 12) + 
  (currentDate.Month - testDate.Month));
```

Now - if you want to compare 2 days in the yyyym format instead of using current date, just do the year/month conversion listed above and then perform the month dif formula on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class **DateDiff** class from the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET), to calculate the months:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void CalcMonths( DateTime epoch )
{
  DateDiff dateDiff = new DateDiff( DateTime.Now, epoch );
  Console.WriteLine( "{0} months", dateDiff.Months );
  // > 1 Year 4 Months 12 Days 12 Hours ago
} // CalcMonths
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a code snippet from the solution posted on MSDN ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287590%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)):

```
DateTime oldDate = new DateTime(2002,7,15);
DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now;

// Difference in days, hours, and minutes.
TimeSpan ts = newDate - oldDate;
// Difference in days.
int differenceInDays = ts.Days;
```

Should work for years/months as well (something like the following):

```
int differenceInMonths = (ts.Years *12 + ts.Months);
```

Hope this will help.
Rgds, AB

Comment: I don't think you can get months from straight from a timespan

Comment: @Greg: thanks for your comments. I have added a clarification regarding TimeSpan object usage for this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically split the string.

```
int a = 201410;
int b= 20139;

int year1 = int.Parse(a.ToString().Substring(0,4));
int year2 = int.Parse(b.ToString().Substring(0,4));

int month1 = int.Parse(a.ToString().Substring(4));
int month2 = int.Parse(b.ToString().Substring(4));

//now construct a date for each
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(year1, month1, 1);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(year2, month2, 1);

//then subtract them and make it months
int numberOfMonths = ((date1.Year - date2.Year) * 12) + date1.Month - date2.Month;
```